# How do I check if a class file has been changed before serializing it?

Tags: c#, algorithm

We have a custom serialization process for a large number of C# types. However, regenerating all serialization information for all classes/types is time consuming and we were planning on optimizing the serialization process by computing the hash of the file and if different, we generate the serialized output, else we skip it. **EDIT:** We can store the hashes in a Dictionary which could be output to a file and re-read when processing. That's the current idea.

Our current serialization processor works as follows - we add the types to be serialized to a repo:

```
SerializerRepo.Add(typeof(MyType)); //Add type to be serialized to a repo
```

And then (possibly elsewhere in code) have the serializer process the repo and output the custom XMLs etc.,

```
Serializer.WriteXML(SerializerRepo.GetTypes());
```

`WriteXML` goes through each type and spews out an XML file for each type at a particular location. I need to optimize the `WriteXML` method to only serialize the class/type if it has changed, else let it be.

This may not be the best way to do it and is open for refactoring suggestions. However, the current problem is how to ascertain if the class definition (or file) housing the class/type has changed in order to determine if the XML should be generated or not?

Since there is no inherent relation between the type and the corresponding class since a class can be partial, .Net doesn't have any such mapping from types to class file and vice versa. However, we don't have any partial classes. But in our case, we seem to need the two (albeit unrelated) pieces of information - the file housing the type/class and the type itself.

Two (possibly sub-optimal) ideas so far:

1. Either we have the user specify the file name along with the type. But that'd not be amenable to any kind of refactoring where the file name is changed.
2. Another solution is to manually read each .cs file and parse for `public class <classname>` and map it to every type. That seems like a huge overhead and not sure if it's a reliable way to do it.

These are the only two ideas that I have but nothing concrete. Suggestions?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? Is it the serialization, or writing the file? I have a feeling that serializing and writing anyway vs opening the file and computing the hash/comparing is going to be just as expensive and time consuming. Can you store hash information inside the XML? Maybe have an index file that stores all the hashes?

Comment: Somewhere you would have to hold on to a hash value of some sort at the time it is serialized, to have something to compare it to later.

Comment: Can't u just compare the previously serialized XML to the class def and check diff.

Comment: Using something like PostSharp you could apply an attribute to the classes that are serializable. Then at compile time you can have the postsharp attribute check the class for changes and generating your hash.

Comment: @RonBeyer - The bottle neck is the `WriteXML` method. It parses the entire class file and generates information that is output into an XML. Scale this to about 1000+ files and it gets really slow.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel - that is a huge overhead. An external service consumes the XMLs. In order to check that, we'll have to reconstruct the class definition from XML and that's not entirely possible since we lose some mapping information as part of the serialization. It'll be a huge overhead to do that.

Comment: Is your WriteXML single or multiple threaded? If single, is it on a main thread or a background thread?

Comment: @jwatts1980 - not sure what you're thinking, but it's single threaded and part of the main thread. It can be made a background thread, but a separate process is dependent on those XMLs being generated. So, it's the file generation time I need to shorten if possible and not perceived processing time.

Comment: @PhD is WriteXML writing to disk? I think Ron Beyer was trying to get at the distinction between the creation of an in-memory representation of XML versus persisting that representation to disk.  It would be really surprising if creating the XML in-memory were slow compared to the actual writing to disk.

Comment: U want speed but use XML and then store it on a disk...ur choosing the slowest things possible to try and make something fast.  Ur architecture needs a good lookin at.

Comment: @PhD I understand a little better having reread the post. Serialization to XML is slow. Writing to a disk is slow. A good way to speed it up: do more of it at a time, in memory, and reduce waiting. Have a thread that is scanning for files and passing them to a group of serialization queues, each on their own thread. The serialization queues generate the XML files, then pass the in-memory xmldocs to another queue (also on it's own thread) that writes to the disk.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel - XML is the unfortunate state of affairs. The consuming interface is outside my control. Custom serialization is way better than manually typing out the XML. But if I do that, then I have the problem above. I can generate the XML in memory or write it out to disk - there is a separate method to get the in memory representation. WriteXML just calls it internally.

Comment: why is something consuming xml files though.why would the other service just not load the dll where these classes are stored...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the generation of XML in-memory from persisting it to disk.

Keep a dictionary from fully-qualified class names to hashes.  On your first run, the dictionary will start out empty.

When it is time to ensure that a class's corresponding XML is up to date on disk, generate its XML in-memory, hash that, and check the hash against the dictionary.  If the class's name is not in the dictionary or if its hash disagrees with the hash in the dictionary, persist the generated XML and update the dictionary with the new hash.

After you've gone through this process with all your types, you'll have a full dictionary of hashes.  Persist that to disk and load it the next time you run this program.

Comment: Pseudocode would be a helpful addition to the text.